# Design an algorithm for efficiently computing the k smallest numbers of the form a+b*sqrt(2)

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics

Full question: Numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{q}$, where $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers, and $q$ is an integer which is not he square of another integer, have special properties, e.g. they are closed under addition and multiplication. For $q=2$, some of the first few numbers of this form are given: $0 + 0\sqrt{2}, 1 + 0\sqrt{2}, 0 + 1\sqrt{2},\ldots$

Design an algorithm for efficiently computing the $k$ smallest numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ for nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$.

(Hint: systematically enumerate points.)

I have the solution available. The first paragraph is: "A key fact about $\sqrt{2}$ is that it is irrational, i.e., it cannot equal to $a/b$ for any integers $a,b$. This implies that if $x + y\sqrt{2} = x' + y'\sqrt{2}$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers, then $x = x'$ and $y = y'$ (since otherwise $\sqrt{2} = (x-x')/(y-y')$).

I just don't see how knowing that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational helps to reason about the problem, especially how it's a "key fact".

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the solution, it is difficult to say. Presumably, had $\sqrt{q}$ been rational, the solution would become more complicated due to the fact that several numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt{q}$ could coincide.

Comment: I suggest you try replacing $\sqrt{2}$ with $\sqrt{4}$ and see what happens in the resulting algorithm.  Is the algorithm still correct?  Does the same proof correctness still go through?

Comment: The brute force solution involves just generating all combinations of a, b for 0 <= a, b <= k. So it's k^2, and then sorting and returning the first k. Not optimal at all. The second solution recognizes that we don't need that many solutions, we can instead create a BST of the form {a,b} and initialize it with the value {0,0}. Then we repeatedly add {BST.min.a +1, BST.min.b}, {BST.min.a, BST.min.b +1} to the BST, and remove the minimum after that, adding it to a result set. This gives O(k log k). The final solution gets O(n) by keeping two pointers i,j in a vector and tracking the smallest a,b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this exercise is to notice that there are at least $k$ numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt{2}$ smaller than $\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor + \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor \sqrt{2}$ (namely, those with $0 \leq a,b \leq \sqrt{k}$). Conversely, every such number of the form $a + b \sqrt{2}$ must have $a,b \leq (1 + \sqrt{2})\sqrt{k}$. Therefore we could simply take all $O(k)$ values of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b \leq (1+\sqrt{2})\sqrt{k}$, find the $k$th smallest in time $O(k)$, and then go over the list in $O(k)$ and output the $k$ smallest elements. The entire algorithm runs in time $O(k)$ (ignoring the cost of arithmetic operations).

This algorithm needs to compare two numbers of the form $a + b\sqrt{2}$. This can be done as follows. Suppose we want to determine whether $a + b \sqrt{2} \leq c + d \sqrt{2}$. If $a = c$ then this happens iff $b \leq d$, and similarly if $b = d$ then this happens iff $a \leq c$. Suppose, without loss of generality, that $d > b$. If also $c > a$ then $a + b \sqrt{2} < c + d \sqrt{2}$, so suppose that $a > c$. Then
$$
a + b \sqrt{2} \leq c + d \sqrt{2} \Leftrightarrow
a-c \leq (d-b) \sqrt{2} \Leftrightarrow
\frac{a-c}{d-b} \leq \sqrt{2} \Leftrightarrow \\
\left(\frac{a-c}{d-b}\right)^2 \leq 2 \Leftrightarrow
(a-c)^2 \leq 2(d-b)^2.
$$

What would happen to this approach if we replaced $\sqrt{2}$ by, say, 2? Then there are only $O(\sqrt{k})$ numbers smaller than $\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor + 2\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor$, since not all combinations of the form $a + 2b$ for $0 \leq a,b \leq \sqrt{k}$ are distinct. Indeed, we need to take the upper bound on $a,b$ to be *linear* in $k$ in order to find the $k$ smallest values of the form $a + 2b$. So the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ does make a big difference for the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. One moment while I work through this.